Differences-in-differences where the treatment affects the sensitivity to another variable
I have a case where agents respond to a variable $X$, such that
$$y_t = \beta^{P,T} X_t + \varepsilon_t $$
$\beta^{P, T}$ can differ for the treated ($T = 1$) and untreated groups, and also the post-treatment ($P = 1$) and pre-treatment times. Therefore, in my model the treatment affects the sensitivity of the groups to $X$.
I am thinking of estimating this using differences-in-differences with interactions, where:
$$ y_t = \alpha X_t + \gamma T X_t + \lambda P X_t + \delta (P * T) X_t + e_t $$
So that $\beta^{0, 0} = \alpha, \quad \beta^{0, 1} = \alpha + \gamma$, etc.
However, the only complication is that there are multiple time periods (t) in my differences-in-differences. My case seems simple, though it is not quite a continuous treatment ($X_t$ differs before the treatment time) nor heterogeneous treatment effects (only one treated and control group). Therefore, I am not sure the new DiD literature covers a case like this, and I am also not sure that I can simply use two way fixed effects to estimate the coefficient on $\delta$. Do you have any suggestions?
